# Trying to fill table element by id with casperjs

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, screen-scraping, casperjs

```
casper.thenEvaluate(function(text){
    document.querySelector("#inputValue").value=text
})
```

casper.thenEvaluate seems to not accept the argument and it is filling undefined in the webpage.

Comment: I am not an expert but it seems like there should be a term set in the call of `thenEvaluate` method. something  like `casper.thenEvaluate(function(text){
    document.querySelector("#inputValue").value=text
}, 'term here')`
http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#thenevaluate

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentations you should use "thenEvaluate" after "start" like this:

```
// Querying for "Chuck Norris" on Google
casper.start('http://google.fr/').thenEvaluate(function(term) {
    document.querySelector('input[name="q"]').setAttribute('value', term);
    document.querySelector('form[name="f"]').submit();
}, 'Chuck Norris');

casper.run();
```

source:

```
http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#thenevaluate
```

Answer (score 0):

Since evaluate runs in browser context(instead of Casper one) you have to explicitly provide variables after the callback function definition. Please check example from the docs

```
casper.evaluate(function(username, password) {
  document.querySelector('#username').value = username;
  document.querySelector('#password').value = password;
  document.querySelector('#submit').click();
}, 'sheldon.cooper', 'b4z1ng4');
```

Note that username param in callback corresponds to `sheldon.cooper` and password param corresponds to `b4z1ng4`.